# mono-complete source code embedded Linux ARM

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, filenotfoundexception

I'm looking for the complete source code for mono (used for cross compilation on ARM platform).

I have been able to compile mono itself (https://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/) and created a simple hello world application which works, however, when I want to use other functionallities, like 'system.io.serialports', the following error is displayed by the application:

> $ mono hello_world.exe
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. File
>   name: 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. File
>   name: 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

This tells me that the System.IO assembly is not compiled with the mono package I've compiled (see the link up top).

Does anyone know where to find the complete source code that I can use for cross-compilation?

Regards,

Daan